# How to truncate C char*?

Tags: c, string, char

As simple as that. I'm on C++ btw. I've read the cplusplus.com's cstdlib library functions, but I can't find a simple function for this.
I know the length of the char, I only need to *erase* last three characters from it. I can use C++ string, but this is for handling files, which uses char*, and I don't want to do conversions from string to C char.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you don't need to copy the string somewhere else and can change it

```
/* make sure strlen(name) >= 3 */
namelen = strlen(name); /* possibly you've saved the length previously */
name[namelen - 3] = 0;
```

If you need to copy it (because it's a string literal or you want to keep the original around)

```
/* make sure strlen(name) >= 3 */
namelen = strlen(name); /* possibly you've saved the length previously */
strncpy(copy, name, namelen - 3);
/* add a final null terminator */
copy[namelen - 3] = 0;
```

Answer (score 9):

I think some of your post was lost in translation.

To truncate a string in C, you can simply insert a terminating null character in the desired position. All of the standard functions will then treat the string as having the new length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[] = "one one two three five eight thirteen twenty-one";

    printf("%s\n", string);

    string[strlen(string) - 3]  = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you know the length of the string you can use pointer arithmetic to get a string with the last three characters:

```
const char* mystring = "abc123";
const int len = 6;

const char* substring = mystring + len - 3;
```

Please note that `substring` points to the same memory as `mystring` and is only valid as long as `mystring` is valid and left unchanged. The reason that this works is that a c string doesn't have any special markers at the beginning, only the `NULL` termination at the end.

*I interpreted your question as wanting the last three characters, getting rid of the start, as opposed to how David Heffernan read it, one of us is obviously wrong.*

Answer (score 1):

It might help to understand how C `char*` "strings" work:

You start reading them from the char that the char* points to until you hit a `\0` char (or simply 0).

So if I have

```
char* str = "theFile.nam";
```

then `str+3` represents the string `File.nam`.

But you want to remove the last three characters, so you want something like:

```
char str2[9];
strncpy (str2,str,8); // now str2 contains "theFile.#" where # is some character you don't know about
str2[8]='\0'; // now str2 contains "theFile.\0" and is a proper char* string.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool TakeOutLastThreeChars(char* src, int len) {
  if (len < 3) return false;
  memset(src + len - 3, 0, 3);
  return true;
}
```

I assume mutating the string memory is safe since you did say *erase* the last three characters. I'm just overwriting the last three characters with "NULL" or 0.

Comment: `memset` seems a trifle strong