# C - char pointers with getline() to read from a text file. Why does this happen? How to improve my workaround?

Tags: c, pointers, char, posix, getline

Quick premise: I solved what I wanted to do thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480440/how-to-truncate-c-char) question, but I still want to understand how C works in this scenario.

I have a plain text file similar to this one (let's call it my_file):

```
11
alpha
23.45
beta
```

I wrote a function, inside a .c file, that reads each line of that file and stores all those values according to a custom `struct` I created. Let's say it is:

```c
struct myStruct
{
    int value1;
    char *value2;
    double value3
    char *value4;
} my_struct;
```

This is the function (not working) I had written:

```c
void myFunct(char *my_file_path, struct myStruct *my_struct)
{
    FILE *my_file = fopen(my_file_path, "r");
    int line_out;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    if (my_file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not open file");
    }

    if ((line_out = getline(&line, &len, my_file)) != -1)
    {
        my_struct->value1 = atoi(line);
    }
    else
        perror("Error reading line of file");

    if ((line_out = getline(&line, &len, my_file)) != -1)
    {
        my_struct->value2 = line;
    }
    else
        perror("Error reading line of file");

    if ((line_out = getline(&line, &len, my_file)) != -1)
    {
        my_struct->value3 = atof(line);
    }
    else
        perror("Error reading line of file");

    if ((line_out = getline(&line, &len, my_file)) != -1)
    {
    
        my_struct->value4 = line;
    }
    else
        perror("Error reading line of file");

    fclose(my_file);
}
```

Notice I passed the struct instance as a pointer.
That said, calling the function produces the following result (terminal output via `printf`):

```sh
value1: 11
value2: beta

value3: 23.450000
value4: beta
```

So there are two issues: the `line` "pointer to pointer" (right?) seems to jump to the next position and affect the previous entry (this is understandable, but I am not sure ho to avoid that without creating new variables), and there is the addition of a `\n` at the end of the string, which I do not know where it comes from.

I do not understand how this works very well in general, and I would also like to know some clever ideas to solve this problem.
In case someone needs it (but there will be surely better solutions in the replies), I have modified my function like this:

```c
void myFunct(char *my_file_path, struct myStruct *my_struct)
{
    FILE *my_file = fopen(my_file_path, "r");
    int line_out;
    char *line = NULL;
    char *line2 = NULL;
    char *line4 = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    if (my_file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Could not open file");
    }

    if ((line_out = getline(&line, &len, my_file)) != -1)
    {
        my_struct->value1 = atoi(line);
    }
    else
        perror("Error reading line of file");

    if ((line_out = getline(&line2, &len, my_file)) != -1)
    {
        line2[strlen(line2) - 1]  = '\0';
        my_struct->value2 = line2;
    }
    else
        perror("Error reading line of file");

    if ((line_out = getline(&line, &len, my_file)) != -1)
    {
        my_struct->value3 = atof(line);
    }
    else
        perror("Error reading line of file");

    if ((line_out = getline(&line4, &len, my_file)) != -1)
    {
    
        line4[strlen(line4) - 1]  = '\0';
        my_struct->value4 = line4;
    }
    else
        perror("Error reading line of file");

    fclose(my_file);
}
```

This is not very scalable, but it gets the job done.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You can remove the trailing newline with `if (line_out > 0 && line[line_out - 1] == '\n') line[line_out - 1] = '\0';` (I can't picture a situation where `getline()` would return 0, but I also like being paranoid about out of bounds array accesses, hence the greater-than-0 check)

Comment: Set `line` to `NULL` before each call to `getline()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getline()` only allocates a new line buffer if the `line` argument points to a null pointer or it doesn't point to enough space. Otherwise it reuses the same buffer that was passed to it. So every time you do

```
my_struct->something = line;
```

you may be saving pointers to the same string.

Use `strdup()` to make a copy of the string.

```
my_struct->something = strdup(line);
```

Don't forget to `free(line)` at the end of the function, since it's no longer needed when you make these copies.

The `\n` at the end of the string is the newline that ended the user's input.  It says it clearly in the `getline()` [documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

> The buffer is null-terminated and includes the newline character, if one was found.

This is just like `fgets()`. You can easily remove it:

```
if (line[strlen(line)-1] == '\n') {
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: No need for `strlen()` since `getline()` returns the length of the line already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, makes sense. Just a quick note, I actually read the documentation but overlooked that part because of the "if one was found" part. I do not know why but I was convinced that there were no `\n` in those lines, maybe because of the `atoi()` and `atof()` outputs not featuring it. I know it is stupid, but that's probably what I was thinking. I now understood my errors.
Thank you again for your help

Comment: The only case where newline wouldn't be found is if the line ends with EOF.